# How to share a function between two AWK instances within a shell script?

Tags: bash, function, awk

```
awk 'function test(){print "aaaa" $1} test()' $1
```

I want to use the same function in another awk instance in the same shell script:

```
awk '{print $3; test()}' $2
```

Is there a way to share this function?

Comment: The function doesn’t look long enough to raise performance concerns if each `awk` must parse it again… What exactly are you trying to achieve? Maybe store the function in a Bash variable and expand it as a prefix to each `awk` script…?